# Xcode 4.6.1 crashes when debugger uses LLDB

Tags: xcode

Xcode 4.6.1 keeps on crashing using LLDB debugger on my new mac mini.
Could anyone help me what's happening? It is ok to use GDB but I rather use the default debugger so I won't have to change it every time I run/test new projects.

I've read something about editing /etc/hosts to have 127.0.0.1 localhost but it wasn't working.

Here are some of the details whenever my Xcode crashes.

```
Process:         Xcode [220]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         4.6.1 (2067)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-2067000000000000~2
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [133]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2013-04-04 10:08:23.876 +0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.3 (12D78)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          11460 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           4
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  5582 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   4
Anonymous UUID:                      F7A4E172-EA44-2180-5471-22ADD0DA75A1

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4H512
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): -[__NSCFString alloc]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4008c2040
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff8ffacaee __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x00007fff856553f0 objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  2  0x00007fff9004340a -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] (in CoreFoundation)
  3  0x00007fff8ff9b02e ___forwarding___ (in CoreFoundation)
  4  0x00007fff8ff9ae18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 (in CoreFoundation)
  5  0x000000010c2f00a6 -[DBGLLDBDebugLocalService operationWorkerWithLaunchSession:error:] (in DebuggerLLDBService)
  6  0x000000010c3505ba -[IDERuniPhoneSimulatorService operationWorkerWithLaunchSession:error:] (in IDEiPhoneSupport)
  7  0x0000000104c6a017 -[IDERunDestination runOperationForLaunchSession:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
  8  0x0000000104c68c87 -[IDELaunchSchemeAction
```

Answer (score 1):

It happened with me also. Esp with SIGABRT at main class. I was advised to debug. I did try lldb debugging. It worked for one app. You need to find which register is it throwing the error. To find that you need to first type in debugging window (when its lldb error only!)

```
register read
```

and then you'll find the error in which register it being raised. then follow the following statements. If eax is the register..

```
po $eax
po [$eax class]
po [$eax name]
po [$eax reason]
```

Then you'll know what changes you have to make in code. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this happens even if you create a new project like a single-window application.

Comment: Problem SOLVED! I removed the sym link on Python's VERSIONS folder called Current as it was looking for 2.7 .  Anyway I just reinstalled Python as well and everything went well.